# Javascript: Perform operation on every element in array and concat result to another array

Tags: javascript, arrays, spotify

In the code below I call the bottom function and I am wanting to take an album (tracks) json retrieved from the spotify api, loop through its tracks, do an operation on every track id, and attach the results to an already existing array and am having issues.

```
export const getTrackData = (token, key) => {
    return getAudioFeaturesTrack(token, key).then((response) => {
        return (
            [
                {
                    "x": response.valence * 100,
                    "y": response.energy * 100
                }
            ]
        )
    });
}

export const getAlbumData = (token, key) => {
    let info = [];
    return getAlbumsTracks(token, key).then((response) => {
        response.items.forEach((track, index) => {
            return getTrackData(token, track.id).then((response) => {
                info = info.concat(response);
            });
        })

        return info;
    });
}
```

when I call the bottom function (getAlbumData) returned is an empty array. I have tested the relevant api calls and getTrackData to ensure they are working and am not sure why getAlbumData is returning an empty array. Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: Your `getTrackData` returns a promise which is asynchronous. You are returning `info` before this inner `forEach` even starts.

Answer (score 1):

You might find it cleaner to use some async/await for this task, for example

```js
export const getTrackData = async (token, key) => {
  const features = await getAudioFeaturesTrack(token, key);
  return {x: features.valence * 100, y: features.energy * 100};
};

export const getAlbumData = async (token, key) => {
  const tracks = await getAlbumsTracks(token, key);
  const trackPromises = tracks.items.map(track => getTrackData(token, track.id));
  const info = await Promise.all(trackPromises);
  return info;
}
```

Comment: thank you very much this worked for me. I needed an array of objects from getAlbumData so I removed the array brackets from getTrackData. There was originally another part of the code called getTrackData that needed an array but I made some changes and your solution works great so far.

Comment: Right, that makes sense, your use of concat would have taken care of that extra array level, I'll update the example.  Since async/await can be used interchangeably with promises, I much prefer the simplicity and clarity of async/await code given the choice.